# JPA rollback nested Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, micronaut

How to rollback nested transactions? let suppose if there is an exception in method5 then how to rollback method4 changes as well.

```
@Singleton
public class Case {
   @Inject
   CaseService caseService;
    
    @Transactional
    void method2(){
        var value = caseService.method4();
        caseService.method5(value);
    }
}

@Singleton
public class CaseService {
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public String method4(){
        return "some";
    }
    
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void method5(String value){
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why not use the default transactional type - REQUIRED? If default is used, it will work as you exptected.

Comment: Why are method4 and method5 separate transactions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rollback `method4` call, then its statements should be within the same transaction as `method5`.

In the code that you provided `method4` and `method5` are always executed in separate transactions.

So, you could remove `REQUIRES_NEW` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`REQUIRES_NEW` will always create a new transaction irrespective of any previous transaction. So, any rollback will happen only to that transaction. You want all of them (`method4`, `method5`) means `method2` should be atomic. In that case, all of them should be under the same transaction which means you just have to use `REQUIRED` only or based on your use case start a new transaction on `method2` and `method4` and `method5` should have REQUIRED.

If any of your transactional methods throws `RuntimeException` then they will be rolled back automatically. If you expect the rollback for checked exceptions also, then you would need to mention that in the annotation.

`(rollbackFor=CustomException.class)`